# django: посчитать разницу между датами

Tags: python, html, django, post

Нужно посчитать кол-во дней между датами, которые водятся клиентом сайта, при этом не заносить их в базу данных

Вот мой html код:

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<body>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p>
            От: <input type="date" name="date_from">
        </p>
        <p>
            До: <input type="date" name="date_befor">
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
    </form>
</body>
```

Код views.py

```
from django.views.generic import View


class IndexView(View):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       
        if request.method == 'POST':
            date_from = request.POST['date_from']
            date_before = request.POST['date_before']

        return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Мне нужно получить разницу между date_from и date_before, но у меня не получается их взять у клиента даже. При нажатии на кнопку получаю следующие ошибки

```
Method Not Allowed (POST): /
Method Not Allowed: /
[02/Apr/2021 09:55:04] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 0
```

Comment: зачем вам испоьзовать форму в django если вы ее не используете в шаблоне?

Comment: О, ребус!
Вопрос к автору @ЕгорКопица

Смотрим на метод формы - ```POST```,  смотрим view - метод ```GET```
Почему метод not allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

как по мне то использование формы django в данном примере избыточно.
Проще сделать так

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>
        От: <input type="date" name="start_date" >
    </p>
    <p>
        До: <input type="date" name="end_date" >
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Для каждого инпута в  форме нужно задать уникальный атрибут name чтобы получить доступ во `views`

и во views

```
from django.views.generic import View

class IndexView(View):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            delta_time = request.POST['start_date'] - request.POST['end_date']

        return render(request, 'index.html',{'delta_time':delta_time })
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'index.html')
```

и дальше уже в шаблоне вывести `delta_time` в нужном месте

Comment: Понял и внес ваш код, но выдает ошибку 405:
Method Not Allowed (GET): /
Method Not Allowed: /

Comment: @ЕгорКопица ну да. Метод get тоже надо определить.